# How can I transfer Clash of Clans data into Game Center?

Tags: iphone, game-center, clash-of-clans

I was transferring stuff from a 4s to a 5s and accidentally deleted Clash of Clans off of Game Center. It is still stored on my old phone, but not in Game Center. Is there any way that I can transfer it? I have put a lot of time and some money into that game.

Answer (score 2):

it's easy to do if you have the old phone handy.
download clash on the 5s and play through the tutorial but don't make any town hall upgrades or buy anything with real money, then on the 5s navigate settings>link device and select new device. you'll be able to get a code from your old phone to transfer villages.